# How to update an existing record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Books model and it has CRUD operations. In config/routes.rb, I have declared

```
map.resources :books
```

My new.html.erb looks like as:

```
<%= form_for :book, url: books_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.submit :Add %>
<% end %>
```

My create method in controller looks like as:

```
def create
  book = Book.new(authorized_params)
  book.save
end
```

So, when I submit my form from views, request would go to the 'create' method and an record for the book gets created in database. Fair enough. Now, I want to have an edit page for book. So, my edit method in controller look like as:

```
def edit
  @book = Book.find_by(params[:id])
  render :new
end
```

When I go to my edit view, it automatically show the value of title in the text box, which is what I expected.. But when I try to submit the form again(ofcourse after changing the title value) it again creates a new record instead of updating it..

Something basic which I missed out in my reading? I googled about it though but did not find satisfactory answer.

Comment: where is your 'update` method?

Comment: Sontya, how does it matter if action is already set to 'create' in edit.html.erb? Or does it implicitly call 'update' method. Well, it does'nt look like. I have an update method  in my controller but request is still going to 'create'.

Comment: post your `edit` form

Comment: Please notice that I have rendered new.html.erb from edit method..

Comment: render `edit` form, `<%= form_for(@book) do |f| %>` which form should like this

Comment: .. ?  I do not want to create the another view form i.e. edit view.

Comment: `def new
  @book = Book.new
  render template: 'edit'
end

def edit 
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
end`, save your `new.html.erb` as `edit.html.erb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are using the 'new' view where form has the post method. If you will check the generated routes, post will be for create method, that is adding a new record. You will have to create a new view for edit where the form target URL will be edit_book_path(@book) and method will be patch. Patch method will route to 'update' function in your controller where you will call @book.update. I am not writing the exact code, but these directions should help you achieve what you want

Comment: Hi Nitigyan, I know that. I could have done that as well but I do not want to create the another view form i.e. edit view. Is'nt there any other such a thing to avoid creating a  new view?

Comment: The view is not the limitation I think but the method and target URL of the form is. When you have to save the edits, update function in the controller needs to be called along with the id of the object to be edited. The 'patch' method of the form will define that the 'update' method is called and the target URL will have the ID. If somehow you can make these things dynamic in your new.html.erb you can make it work buy single view. But I would suggest you go by the standard convention of RoR, otherwise you may end up with a confusing code and will put unnecessary effort

Comment: So, you are suggesting me to create another view edit.html.erb which will look like as something like this:

`<%= form_for :book, url: edit_books_path, :method => "patch" do |f| %>
`<%= f.label :title %>
`<%= f.text_field :title %>
`<%= f.submit :Add %>
`<% end %>

Comment: Yes, url will be book_path(@book) and I believe you already have an 'update' function in your controller. Check the 5.11 section of http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html for simple example.

Comment: Mate, this is not what I wanted to do but seems like this is the only elegant way to do it.. Thanks..

Comment: Yes I understand but probably such limitations are in fact strengths of RoR and follow it's 'Convention over configuration' ideology. Will you mark my answer as correct :)